# Transferring arguments to a function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I want to pass a list of input arguments to a function. Something like:

```
list = {a1, a2, a3};
expression = a1 + a2^2 + a3^2;
f = Function[list, Evaluate[expression]];
```

and `f[1,2,3]` must evaluate to `14`. Is there any way to use the list for `f` instead of using

```
f = Function[{a1,a2,a3}, Evaluate[expression]]
```

Comment: f[a_, b_, c_] := a + b^2 + c^2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I won't be surprised if this is a duplicate, but it's easier for me to write an answer:

```
Function@@{list, expression}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

For the argument to be either a list or a sequence

```
f[x__ /; (Length[Flatten[{x}]] == 3)] := Total[Flatten[{x}]^{1, 2, 2}]
```

For example,

```
{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[a1, a2, a3], f[1, 2, 3]}

(* {a1 + a2^2 + a3^2, 14, a1 + a2^2 + a3^2, 14} *)
```