# Change format of vector for input argument of function

Tags: warning-messages

I have a function f defined as

```
list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6};
expression = a1 + a2^2 + a3^2 + a4 + a5*a6;
f = Function @@ {list, expression};
```

The input in vector is something likes

```
listin = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

but when using

```
f[listin]
```

it informs error:"Too many parameters in {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6} to be filled from \Function[{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6},a1+a2^2+a3^2+a4+a5\ a6][{1,2,3,4,5,6}]".

I wonder is there any way to change format of the listin to make it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6};
expression = a1 + a2^2 + a3^2 + a4 + a5*a6;
f = Function @@ {list, expression};

listin = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

The argument to `f` is a sequence, so you need to `Apply` (`@@`) the function `f`

```
f @@ listin

(* 48 *)
```

Alternatively, convert the input to a `Sequence`

```
f[Sequence @@ listin]

(* 48 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the resource function [TensorPureFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TensorPureFunction/):

```
f = ResourceFunction["TensorPureFunction"][{expression}][{list}]

f[listin][[1]]

(*48*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would use `Apply` as [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) has shown in his answer.

But just for fun:

```
ReplaceAt[listin, List->f,0]

(* 48 *)
```

Or:

```
ReplaceAt[listin, List->ReplaceAt[{list,expression}, List->Function,0],0]

(* 48 *)
```

But, as shown in previous neat answers ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283400/106) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283372/106)), the above is equivalent to the following:

```
(Function@@{list,expression})@@listin 

(* 48 *)
```

Or:

```
g={list,expression};g[[0]]=Function;

g@@listin

(* 48 *)
```

Or (! modification in place):

```
ClearAll[gg]

gg={list,expression};gg[[0]]=Function;
x=listin;x[[0]]=gg;
gg//OutputForm
x

(*                                            
Function[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}, a1 + a2^2  + a3^2  + a4 + a5 a6]
48
*)
```

Comment: (+1) I had already seen this use of `ReplaceAt` in another answer of yours, I find it very useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an expression,

```
a1 + a2^2 + a3^2 + a4 + a5*a6
```

that you want to be the body of a function, and you also know the exact order of the arguments to that function, in your case given by

```
list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}
```

, then why are you going through the trouble to force these argument names into your function definition? You could just as easily do this:

```
f = Function[Null, #1 + #2^2 + #3^2 + #4 + #5 #6]
```

To demonstrate:

```
f @@ list
```

`a1 + a2^2 + a3^2 + a4 + a5 a6`